# How to pop array from multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Actually I want pop first array from multi dimensional array and my array having free and weight array when "weight" array is coming I need to pop "free" array otherwise no please help me out someone.

```
Array (
    [free] => Array (
        [title] => Free Shipping
        [quote] => Array (
            [free] => Array (
                [code] => free.free
                [title] => Free Shipping
                [cost] => 0
                [tax_class_id] => 0
                [text] => Rs 0
            )
        )
        [sort_order] =>
        [error] =>
    )
    [weight] => Array (
        [title] => Shipping Method - Courier Service
        [quote] => Array (
            [weight_6] => Array (
                [code] => weight.weight_6
                [title] => Courier charged - Karnataka/Andra Pradesh/Kerlala (Weight: 0.00g)
                [cost] => 40.00
                [tax_class_id] => 0
                [text] => Rs 40
            )
        )
        [sort_order] => 1
        [error] =>
    )
)
```

Below is my code,

```
<?php if ($shipping_methods) { ?>
<?php echo "<pre>";
print_r($shipping_methods);
die; ?>
<p><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></p>
<?php foreach ($shipping_methods as $shipping_method) { ?>
    <p><strong><?php echo $shipping_method['title']; ?></strong></p>
    <?php if (!$shipping_method['error']) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
                        <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php echo $quote['title']; ?> - <?php echo $quote['text']; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $shipping_method['error']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: why do you have soooooo many <?php ?> tags ?

Comment: this is scary though

Comment: @elbarto How to pop that array is what I want.

Comment: Have you tried using array_pop?

Comment: @PhpDev that I tried but not getting try to give solution.

Comment: what error did you get when you tried array_pop? Please be specific

Comment: @phpDev am array_pop I have not done yet yar.

Comment: Want to pop first array ? what you mean ? array_pop function deletes last element.. please explain your needs better

Comment: Then try it and come back with an error if so

Comment: You have 2 "free" arrays, which one do you want to get rid of?

Comment: this question is vague. The question says it all. You want to pop an array! PHP has got a function for that. A simple google search would have saved time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_pop like this on multidimensional array

```
  $id = array(
  array(123, "sub1"),
  array(321, "sub2"),
);
$result = array_pop($id);
echo $result[0] .' '. $result[1];
```

output:

> 321 sub2

Array_pop gives you the last element of the array.
For the first array you can use array_shift()

```
  $id = array(
  array(123, "sub1"),
  array(321, "sub2"),
);
$result = array_shift($id);
echo $result[0] .' '. $result[1];
```

output

> 123 sub1

Comment: I tried like below '$result = array_shift($shipping_methods);
echo $result[0] .' '. $result[1];die;' it is throwing undefined index

Comment: can you please post output of var_dump($result[0]);